# Whats the easiest way to completely remove a directory element & all its sub-contents from VOB?

Tags: clearcase

What I know is, using `rmelem` to remove the folder first, and this will cause all of its child elements to be moved to `lost+found`.

Then, go into `lost+found`, and repeatedly execute `rmelem *` until all of the elements are removed.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

The [technote about `lost+found`](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21120317) is quite clear:

if you `rmelem` a directory, all its content will indeed be moved to `lost+found`, where it will has to `lost+found`.  The technote adds:

> Note: If a directory element is deleted from `lost+found` with `rmelem`, its contents will be moved to lost+found in the same manner described in the first section above.

That is why I always try to **`rmelem` files first, then directories**, in order to avoid a trip (or several trips) in `lost+found`.

Except I very rarely [`rmelem` anything](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_rmelem.htm), as the same technote warns:

> Use `rmelem` carefully when deleting elements or symbolic links from the `lost+found` directory.
>   While the content of `lost+found` typically consists of unwanted elements and symbolic links, in some circumstances it can contain elements that are cataloged elsewhere in the VOB (that is, not orphaned) that are associated by symbolic or hard links.
>   For this reason, do not run `rmelem` recursively in `lost+found` without first verifying it contents.
>
> If you need to save an element that is currently in `lost+found`, catalog it in a versioned directory using `mv` as explained in the previous section

Actually, with ClearCase UCM, it is almost impossible to `rmelem` any element with some history, because of all the hyperlink you would compromised (related to baselines mainly).