# Clearcase Delete Directory

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

I have a directory structure like so:

```
root_dir
  dir1
  dir2
    file1.txt
    file2.txt
    sub_dir
      file3.txt
      file4.txt
```

What is the best way to delete `dir2` and all it's sub-elements using `rmname`?  Can I simply do 'cleartool rmname dir2' and have it recursively delete all it's contents?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only need to:

```
cleartool checkout -nc root_dir
cleartool rmname dir2
cleartool checkin root_dir
```

That remove the reference to `dir2` in the new version of `root_dir`, making `dir2` and all its content invisible (not reachable).
And you can easily restore `dir2` (and all its content) by merging the previous version of `root_dir` (which was still referencing `dir2`) with the current version (the one where you rmname'd `dir2`) in order to recreate a new version where you get back `dir2`.

Note: when using `rmname`, you might have an error message mentioning that the element is in checked out, even though it is not checked out in the branch where you are doing the `rmname`.
using `rmname -force` is the solution to still perform the rmname: see [this technote](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21232758).

Comment: That doesn't remove the entire structure from the underlying clearcase database - which is a good and bad thing. ie you can check out the version prior to the rmname and get it all back. Not quite the same as a recursive delete - but probably what you wanted.

Comment: @hawkeye: "but probably what you want": in my experience, this is usually enough. No need to go deeper than that.

Comment: This solution doesn't remove all elements from the VOB, which is a burden on VOB capacity. I suggest you'd delete all the elements by yourself

Comment: @TripleS do you mean `rmelem` instead of `rmname`, to completely remove the element and all its history?

Comment: No , I suggest to delete all elements instead of merely delete the father directory, use rmelem  for each element

Comment: @TripleS so you *do* mean `rmelem`: that can be quite dangerous: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4941527/6309

Comment: I mean rmname, remove symbolic links

Comment: OK. You said "use rmelem for each element", hence my previous comment.