# CC delete option from CC explorer

Tags: version-control, clearcase

I was wondering which command is executed internally when we select 'Delete' from Clearcase explorer context menu. Is it rmname, rmelem or rmbranch? We use base CC.

I am a developer and since I don't want to do any removal related experiments within our CC setup, I decided to ask the question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is [`cleartool rmname`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_rmname.htm).

It will checkout for you the parent directory, derefence the file (rmname) and checkin the parent directory.

See "[About cleartool rmname and checkouts](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21232758)"

> The Delete operation from within ClearCase Explorer on Microsoft® Windows® executes a `cleartool rmname`, not a `cleartool rmelem` or `cleartool rmver`.

Of course, this is valid for a file or a directory (see "[Clearcase Delete Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5986932/6309)").

The nice thing with a `rmname` is that you can cancel it, creating a new version which restores the element (file or directory) that you have "deleted".
See "[Undo remove file in ClearCase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4634373/6309)".