# Accidentally deleted a folder in ClearCase explorer, how to recover that?

Tags: clearcase

I Accidentally deleted a folder in ClearCase explorer, is there anyway to recover that?
(the view was snapshot)

I tried comparing versions and check the version tree but found nothing.

Answer (score 1):

If you have deleted ([rmname'd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17729901/6309)) the folder, then you can easily recover from that.

See "[Undo remove file in ClearCase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4634373/6309)".

But if it was a *new* folder that you didn't yet add to source control, then ClearCase (in a [snapshot view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2925378/6309)) isn't aware of it, and you need to restore it through other tools (like a [Recuva File Recovery](http://www.piriform.com/recuva)).

If it was deleted, but was already in source control, all you need to do (again in a snapshot view) is to use a [`cleartool update`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc%255Fref.doc/topics/ct_update.htm):

```
cleartool update /path/to/parent/folder
```

That will restore the content of the parent folder, including the folder you just erased.