# unable to complete delivery

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I got the following error while trying to complete the posted delivery. Is there anything I can do it from the target site?

```
cleartool: Error: Unable to check out
"/vobs/amit_sumit/lost+found/pcs_i_ltf_odfc_set_sftp.c.842f38e667011e395ad0018fe6508eea".
cleartool: Error: Some files could not be checked out in the target view.
cleartool: Error: Unable to perform merge.
cleartool: Error: Unable to do integration.
cleartool: Error: Unable to deliver stream "banglore_atx_cl".
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

You can change the config spec of the view you are using for your deliver in order to *not* select the `lost+found` folder.

```
cd /path/to/my/view
cleartool edcs
```

Add (as a first rule, at the top)

```
element /vobs/amit_sumit/lost+found -none
```

save and resume your deliver.

Note: depending on what you are merging (a folder within the vob, or the vob itself), you also can add same same selection rule between:

```
#UCMCustomElemBegin - DO NOT REMOVE - ADD CUSTOM ELEMENT RULES AFTER THIS LINE
#UCMCustomElemEnd - DO NOT REMOVE - END CUSTOM ELEMENT RULES
```

But by putting it on top, you are sure it will be taken into account.

That `lost+found` elements will still be part of the deliver, but will be skipped with a warning, as opposed to be blocking.

Comment: For more on the `lost+found` folder, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/4941527/6309.